# Windows Service exceptions on network error

Tags: c#, windows-services

How should I handle exceptions on network errors in a Windows Service? For example when the service fails to connect to the SMTP server. I want the service to continue running when that happens. A simple try catch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please include the code around the try-catch block from where the exception is escaping.

Comment: As I said in my post, it doesn't work. The thread will still be interupted.